# Website horizontal scroll snap to dividers using css

Tags: html, css, web, divider

My problem is i don't know how to snap dividers to lock the scroll on every page.. i found a code that can use css to make it work, but i. can't modify as i want. it doesn't seems working for me:(.. any answers or advices is very acpreciated!.. Thank youuu.

Here's my HTML & CSS code :

```
Code pen : https://codepen.io/faizjie9/pen/rNVqXYY
```

And here's my example what i was expected :

```
Code pen : https://codepen.io/faizjie9/pen/WNvaVpr
```

Comment: Both of those link to the same place. Please can you update one?

Comment: Please paste your code here. Have a look at MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://codepen.io/faizjie9/pen/WNvaVpr

Comment: Copy your code from codepen.io and paste it into your question.

Comment: i'm sorry rahul, i cant paste it to my question here because stackoverflow has a limits of post a code or css, its tell me i have been beyond the limits about 30000 characters.. so i paste it on codepen.